# How does a Romulan quantum singularity work?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Star Trek: The Next Generation, Romulan warbirds use [artificial controlled singularities](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Artificial_quantum_singularity#Artificial_quantum_singularity) as their primary power source.

Is there an **in-universe** explanation how this actually works and/or how the Romulans generate energy from a singularity?

Comment: I don't think you'll find a canon in-universe answer (no real details are given at http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Quantum_singularity for example), but a reasonable guess based on real physics would be that they extract energy from its rotation using the "Penrose Process", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20813/how-would-a-black-hole-power-plant-work

Comment: Another similar one is the "Blandford Znajek" process discussed at http://everything2.com/title/Blandford+Znajek+process -- I think that's actually the one that's illustrated in the physics stack exchange link I gave above.

Comment: I voted to close as this question seems to be asking for an answer to a scientific question, rather than a science fiction one. If you re-word it to make it only pertain to the *Star Trek* universe, I'll withdraw the vote.

Comment: Quick and simple answer: By commanding "Make it so." If there's no lower rank around you, nod and quickly tap some random parts of the screen in front or behind of you. Chances are high, that'll do the trick.

Comment: And I think it's quite possible that there might be a canon answer after all. While the writers were not immune to throwing in a little technobabble, they did come up with explanations (OK, or pseudo-explanations) of how science worked in many cases.

Comment: @MrLister - I'm sure there'll be something. The romulans are a major player and their ships (and indeed their engines) formed the basis for at least two major plotlines that I can think of.

Comment: I'm disappointed that people are voting to close. I've made it clearer that OP is looking for an in-universe answer...

Comment: They use highly advanced GNDN relays.

Comment: It is disappointing to see that this site will close if the question cannot be answered in cannon. The cool thing about Star Trek is that arguments can be made based on science if the cannon doesn't cover it. Yes, such an answer would be pure speculation but I for one would be interested in reading peoples ideas on this sort of thing even if they are crazy ideas.

Comment: Also no details at http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Artificial_quantum_singularity#Artificial_quantum_singularity and http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Romulan_technology#Artificial_quantum_singularity_reactor ...and http://sto.gamepedia.com/Warp_Core says that singularity cores are "fueled by singularity charge" but provides no info on how power is extracted. If all these wikis say nothing about it I really doubt there are any canon sources, any more than there are canon sources for exactly how the special material in the warp nacelles creates a warp field.

Comment: The reddit post at http://www.reddit.com/r/DaystromInstitute/comments/288ays/romulan_propulsion_and_shuttle_speeds/ does note that a black hole with mass 5450 tons would generate Hawking radiation with about the same power output that a Galaxy class shuttle is supposed to have, so for an answer based on real science we could also speculate that they just harvest the Hawking radiation (though they'd have to constantly feed it more mass to avoid a runaway process where it loses all its mass to Hawking radiation, generating power at a greater and greater rate as its mass decreases).

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Oh, ye of little faith. There's always a canon explanation if you dig dig dig hard enough...

Comment: @Richard - nice find! I forgot that there was a writer's manual supplying lots of technical info that was distinct from the published *ST:TNG Technical Manual*.

Answer (score 11):

The [TNG Writer's Manual (4th Season](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Writers%27_Technical_Manual)) makes it clear that Romulan spacecraft generate energy by means of **harnessing the x-ray emissions** from a captive quantum singularity.

[image]

---

In the TNG : "[Timescape](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/251.txt)" we see both the exterior and a partial interior of a Romulan engine core. The singularity itself is missing but this still allows us to make some reasonable assumptions based on what remains:

- The singularity sits in the centre of the engine core, held in place by a series of (black?) [magnetic confinement](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Magnetic_containment_field) rings. These prevent it from colliding with the walls of the chamber when the ship moves.

[image]

- The core itself is flooded with some sort of gas which accelerates towards the gravitic attraction of the singularity at high speeds, creating extreme heat and high levels of energetic **x-ray emissions**.

[image]

- These x-ray emissions are [somehow](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Technobabble) collected, converted into usable energy and this is then channelled into the ship's warp engines in much the same way that the energy created by a normal Federation [Matter/Anti-Matter](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Warp_core) reaction is used.

Comment: I think you answer should mention  Hawking radiation which tells us that tiny singularities evaporate.

Comment: @flq - The question asked for in-universe answers only. I presume the Romulans have found some way to compensate for the loss of mass, possibly by [insert tech mumbo-jumbo here]...

Comment: @flq - the x-rays could be from a mini version of the astrophysical jets seen around real black holes-see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_jet --which are thought to be created by the acceleration of the matter in the "accretion disc" around the black hole (which could explain why they need to pump in a bunch of gas around the artificial black holes). Those jets are thought to be the source of x rays in real black holes, since they are large enough that the Hawking radiation is far too weak to be measured from Earth.

Comment: @Richard - is there a canon source for the idea that the gas in the chamber is specifically the cause of the x-rays? The section you quote doesn't say that, it doesn't even say that there *is* gas in the chamber. Also, in that scene of Geordi looking in the chamber from "Timescape", he was looking at a malfunctioning Romulan engine frozen in time, which had been made "inactive" by an alien life form, not a normally-functioning one, so if your description is based on its appearance in that scene, I don't think that's a good guide to how they are supposed to work.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - As I said in the answer, everything below the line is mere speculation. Literally the only thing I've been able to uncover that isn't already on Memory Alpha/LCARS/Star Trek.com is that the power source was x-ray based.

Comment: @Richard - thanks, I was looking it over quickly and missed the "allows us to make some reasonable assumptions" line.

Comment: @Richard They use Hawking Suppressors, of course!

Answer (score 1):

1. The first answer is the formation of virtual particles in the space surrounding the singularity (as proposed in the real world by Dr. Stephen Hawking). These virtual particles can be interacted with special fluids or targets to generate ions for thrust or power for Romulan Warbirds.
2. The second answer is the 'Seeping effect' of energy described in many science fiction universes. 
   To create a singularity, you need certain amount of energy (insane amount of energy if you consider our Universe, but achievable in Star Trek universe), this makes the singularity artificially made one. The formation of a singularity actually opens up a portal through space and time, (as we have seen in Star Trek reboot). 
   The energy (in the form of gravitons seeping in from the other passage must be great enough to be successfully converted to thrust and power for Romulan Warbirds. Like the immense flow of water through a hole in the sink, the energy seeps in and can be harnessed.

Comment: The question specifically related to in-universe answers, rather than pure speculation.

Comment: But the in-universe answers are just pure speculation on the part of the writers.

Comment: There is a big difference between speculation and _in-universe speculation_. In the first instance you quite literally make it up on the fly, whereas in-universe provides at the very least an agreed upon framework to work with. I.e. pure nonsense vs world-building nonsense. The latter importantly attempts to '_get inside the authors head_'.